# PhantomJS WebPage memory consumption?

Tags: javascript, memory, phantomjs, qtwebkit, casperjs

Is there a programmatic (since i want to do it automatically at runtime) way to see how much memory a webpage uses when running it through PhantomJs?

I am also using casperjs if that could be helpful. I have searched a lot but haven't found any way. PhantomJs uses QtWebKit so I don't have access to window.performance.memory.

I want to have this information since I am setting up automated performance tests for a web application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only way I can see monitoring usage is by using the **top command** in Unix- and the **Task Manager** in Windows environments. Interesting question!

Comment: I'm looking for something like that, I'd like to show the memory usage in a webpage for the purpose of a demo.

I was thinking to node.js that serves the app and monitor the memory.

did you find anything like it?

Answer (score 0):

No, at this time this feature is not supported, but I have found issue about that https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10031