# Measuring memory consumption programmatically in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, automated-tests, phantomjs

Is there a way to have a JavaScript code that would run as an automated test and measure a web-app memory consumption?
What I am looking for is a way to prevent memory leaks in an angular app by having automated tests as a part of CI build process informing me about memory issues as soon as they arise. I already have many JavaScript tests running in PhantomJS via Jasmine.

Comment: No, basically a duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15958395/1816580

Answer (score 0):

I would get that information from the operating system by grepping ps aux for the phantom process.